# How can i only copy folders with robocopy in powershell?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

How can i copy only the folders in a directory with powershell and robocopy?

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\test' |

ForEach-Object {
    $newname = ($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x20-\x5D,\x60-\x7E]+', '-')
    write-host $_.BaseName
    write-host $newname
    robocopy.exe 'C:\temp\test\'$_.BaseName 'C:\temp\test\copy\'$newname
}
```

**Edit**

Thanks works great

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\test' |

ForEach-Object {
    $newname = ($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x20-\x5D,\x60-\x7E]+', '-')
    if (($_.GetType()).Name -eq "DirectoryInfo"){
        write-host "folder"
    }
    write-host $_.BaseName
    write-host $newname
    robocopy.exe "C:\temp\test\$($_.BaseName)" "C:\temp\test\copy\$newname"
}
```

Comment: You are basically renaming `BaseName` to `Copy` and copying everything under `C:\Temp\Test` (which contains `copy` folder as well to again `copy` ). So `copy` will have it's own copy every time you run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected errors, modified code below.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\test' |

ForEach-Object {
    $newname = ($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x20-\x5D,\x60-\x7E]+', '-')
    write-host $_.BaseName
    write-host $newname
    robocopy.exe "C:\temp\test\$($_.BaseName)" "C:\temp\test\copy\$newname"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\test'

foreach($item in $items){
    if(($item.GetType()).Name -eq "DirectoryInfo"){
        $newname = ($item.BaseName -Replace '[^\x20-\x5D,\x60-\x7E]+', '-')
        Write-Host $item.BaseName
        Write-Host $newname
        robocopy.exe "C:\temp\test\$($_.BaseName)" "C:\temp\test\copy\$newname"
    }else{
        Write-Host "$item is not a directory"
    }
}
```