# How to copy **only** the folder content of a directory in powershell script with robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to copy **only** the folders that are within a directory, the script provided in the answer to this question copies all content within the directory: [How can i only copy folders with robocopy in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54694212/how-can-i-only-copy-folders-with-robocopy-in-powershell)

The code from this answer is provided below:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\test' |
ForEach-Object {
    $newname = ($_.BaseName -Replace '[^\x20-\x5D,\x60-\x7E]+', '-')
    if (($_.GetType()).Name -eq "DirectoryInfo"){
        write-host "folder"
    }
    write-host $_.BaseName
    write-host $newname
    robocopy.exe "C:\temp\test\$($_.BaseName)" "C:\temp\test\copy\$newname"
}
```

Comment: [`robocopy /CREATE`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), or [`xcopy /T`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)?

Comment: so I can replace robocopy.exe with one of these you mean?

Comment: I meant that you take a look at the `/CREATE` option of `robocopy` (which is likely unsuitable since it also creates zero-length files), or at the `xcopy` command and its `/T` option (maybe together with `/E`), which is intended to create the destination directory tree without copying any files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to use the parameters:
/E = copy directories even if empty
/XF *.* = Exclude, in this case all files, ie anything with "." in the filename, eg. all files

Example of use:

```
    $Source = "C:\temp\test"
    $Destination = "C:\temp\test2"
    $robocopyOptions = "/E /XF *.*"
    # filelist is required but we will ignore it anyway with parameters we are passing
    $fileList = ''
    robocopy.exe $Source $Destination $fileList $robocopyOptions.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `robocopy` you might also use the [`xcopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), which features an option `/T` to create the destination directory tree without copying any files. Here is an excerpt of the help text when you enter `xcopy /?` into a command prompt window:

> ```cmd
>   /T           Creates directory structure, but does not copy files. Does not
>                include empty directories or subdirectories. /T /E includes
>                empty directories and subdirectories.
> ```

So you could use the following command line:

```cmd
xcopy.exe /T /E /I "C:\temp\test\folder" "C:\temp\test\copy"
```

Comment: yeah great they both work fine but robocopy.exe is slightly faster